# Python regex and find multiple times

Tags: python, regex

I have a little problem with a regex.

I want to find in my text all the "articles" content.
there could be a "chapter" between two articles, but for the moment I pass it.

Here is my text (there is no \n) :

> Chapter 1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,diamArticle 1Maecenas ligula massa,
>   varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitorChapter 2Duis
>   arcu in pedeArticle 2Praesent blandit odio eu eArticle 3Pellentesque
>   sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
>   faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae

To get multiple match, I guess I must use findall().
But my little regex is not working :

```
re.findall(r"""Article\s(?P<number>\d+)(?P<content>.*)""",content,re.UNICODE)
```

The **content** param get all my text. I assume it's because there is **.***
So how the regex can match multiple times in my text?
I don't have to use findall() or my regex is invalid ?

So if anyone has an idea,
Thanks.

Ps : I Want to do this only by using the regex, to progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to swallow everything until you find `Article\s` or the end of input. This can be done using a lazy quantifier followed by a positive lookahead test:

```
re.findall(r"""Article\s(?P<number>\d+)(?P<content>.*?)(?=Article\s|$)""",content,re.UNICODE)
```

Another solution is to split against `Article\s`, but then you'll need to discard the first splitted group. Each splitted group apart from the first would then obey:

```
^(?P<number>\d+)(?P<content>.*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

[`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) is OK. You can extract groups of text from all the matches.

You can also see [this](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/stdlib.html#string-pattern-matching) example.